# DotNetNuke URL rewrite issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke

I would like to shorten this:     http://www.example.com/desktopmodules/imm/ims_cddetail/playtrack.aspx?trackid=18353

to http://www.example.com/playtrack/18353

IIS is no help. It suggests http://www.example.com/trackid/18353 and when I choose that, it doesn't work anyway.

I created a virtual IIS directory in the main site called "playtrack" and pointed it to the proper path. But, I still am left with http://www.example.com/playtrack/playtrack.aspx?trackid=18353.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking in completely the wrong place. Dotnetnuke's Configuration Manager has a section called SiteUrls. I simply entered a rule in that:

```
<RewriterRule>
  <LookFor>[^?]*/playtrack/(\d+)</LookFor>
  <SendTo>~/desktopmodules/imm/ims_cddetail/playtrack.aspx?trackid=$1</SendTo>
</RewriterRule>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx, you will find everything that you need about the url in aspx. You must create custom route type, for more info please read the documentation of microsoft. Especially your question is answered in the topic which called "Adding routes to a web form application".

Comment: Does not apply to Dotnetnuke. I already read it. This is a DNN specific issue.